# why some time file_get_contents not work for file url?

Tags: php

When I use this code in a php file in public_html not working :

```
$badwords = explode("\n", file_get_contents('bad.txt'));
```

but when i add my site url working this code working nice :

```
$badwords = explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://example.com/bad.txt'));
```

What's the problem?

please help me.

thank you.

Comment: It possibly has to do with the the path of the file. I would suggest changing the path so that it is relative to the current script like so `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/bad.txt')`.

Comment: very very thank you . my problem with your help solved . very thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using file_get_contents() function one can do the other sites data scraping and hence most of the time server doesn't allow to use this function  and may be you can get other errors as well.